# Python - how to find all intersections of two strings?

Tags: python, string, algorithm

How to find all intersections (also called the longest common substrings) of two strings and their positions in both strings?

For example, if `S1="never"` and `S2="forever"` then resulted intersection must be `["ever"]` and its positions are `[(1,3)]`. If `S1="address"` and `S2="oddness"` then resulted intersections are `["dd","ess"]` and their positions are `[(1,1),(4,4)]`.

Shortest solution without including any library is preferable. But any correct solution is also welcomed.

Comment: Do the substrings have to appear at the same position in both strings (as they do in both your examples)?

Comment: @aix: no, they can appear in different positions like "never" and "forever". I've changed example.

Comment: What do you mean by "all solutions", if for `"call"` and `"wall"` the right solution is `["all"]` and not `["a", "al", "all", "ll", "l", "l"]`? Do you mean all the maximal solutions? What is the precise definition here?

Comment: And do you care about time complexity, or not so much?

Comment: @julkiewicz: 1:Yes, maximal solutions. 2:Not so much. Just a solution if possible in Python.

Comment: @agf: it's better! But if there is no any, then it's also Ok!

Comment: -0.  Not a fan of these please-write-code-for-me questions.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: it's just an interesting problem, I think it makes a lot of fun to excercise such kind of problems. I personally like it very much and I've solved it already, but it's interesting if anybody can devise an alternative solution.

Comment: @psihodelia:  Then post your code as a jumping off point.

Comment: Code golf & programming puzzles are off-topic for this site. See http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: How large can the strings be? What is the complexity of the solution you want?

Comment: @MAK: it can be as large as any python string. It's complexity is not important yet.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I have discovered a perfectly marvellous method, but this page is not big enough to hold it. If seriously, it's very long and slow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, you're saying that you can't include any library. However, Python's standard [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) contains a function which does exactly what you expect. Considering that it is a Python interview question, familiarity with difflib might be what the interviewer expected.

```
In [31]: import difflib

In [32]: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, "never", "forever").get_matching_blocks()
Out[32]: [Match(a=1, b=3, size=4), Match(a=5, b=7, size=0)]


In [33]: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, "address", "oddness").get_matching_blocks()
Out[33]: [Match(a=1, b=1, size=2), Match(a=4, b=4, size=3), Match(a=7, b=7, size=0)]
```

You can always ignore the last Match tuple, since it's dummy (according to documentation).

Comment: Thank you! I think your method is the best.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done in O(n+m) where `n` and `m` are lengths of input strings.

The pseudocode is:

```
function LCSubstr(S[1..m], T[1..n])
    L := array(1..m, 1..n)
    z := 0
    ret := {}
    for i := 1..m
        for j := 1..n
            if S[i] = T[j]
                if i = 1 or j = 1
                    L[i,j] := 1
                else
                    L[i,j] := L[i-1,j-1] + 1
                if L[i,j] > z
                    z := L[i,j]
                    ret := {}
                if L[i,j] = z
                    ret := ret ∪ {S[i-z+1..z]}
    return ret
```

See the [Longest_common_substring_problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) wikipedia article for more details.

Comment: Yea, that was my first thought, however dynamic programming usually isn't exactly a one-liner.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I could come up with:

```
import itertools

def longest_common_substring(s1, s2):
   set1 = set(s1[begin:end] for (begin, end) in
              itertools.combinations(range(len(s1)+1), 2))
   set2 = set(s2[begin:end] for (begin, end) in
              itertools.combinations(range(len(s2)+1), 2))
   common = set1.intersection(set2)
   maximal = [com for com in common
              if sum((s.find(com) for s in common)) == -1 * (len(common)-1)]
   return [(s, s1.index(s), s2.index(s)) for s in maximal]
```

Checking some values:

```
>>> longest_common_substring('address', 'oddness')
[('dd', 1, 1), ('ess', 4, 4)]
>>> longest_common_substring('never', 'forever')
[('ever', 1, 3)]
>>> longest_common_substring('call', 'wall')
[('all', 1, 1)]
>>> longest_common_substring('abcd1234', '1234abcd')
[('abcd', 0, 4), ('1234', 4, 0)]
```

Comment: @agf that's what it returns... or am i missing something? added a test that shows it returns multiple values

Comment: Updated my answer to include the index of each substring in the two strings. @psihodelia is this what you want?

Comment: Ah, I see. I missed what was meant by maximal. See updated answer.

Comment: Bingo. It makes me shudder to think about the time complexity, something like O(n*(n!) + m*(m!))?

Comment: Yeah, running time is pretty terrible, but it should work fine for small strings anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Batteries included!

The difflib module might have some help for you - here is a quick and dirty side-by-side diff:

```
>>> import difflib
>>> list(difflib.ndiff("never","forever"))
['- n', '+ f', '+ o', '+ r', '  e', '  v', '  e', '  r']
>>> diffs = list(difflib.ndiff("never","forever"))
>>> for d in diffs:
...   print {' ': '  ', '-':'', '+':'    '}[d[0]]+d[1:]
...
 n
     f
     o
     r
   e
   v
   e
   r
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you only want substrings to match if they have the same absolute position within their respective strings. For example, "abcd", and "bcde" won't have any matches, even though both contain "bcd".

```
a = "address"
b = "oddness"

#matches[x] is True if a[x] == b[x]
matches = map(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], zip(list(a), list(b)))

positions = filter(lambda x: matches[x], range(len(a)))
substrings = filter(lambda x: x.find("_") == -1 and x != "","".join(map(lambda x: ["_", a[x]][matches[x]], range(len(a)))).split("_"))
```

positions = `[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]`

substrings = `['dd', 'ess']`

If you only want substrings, you can squish it into one line:

```
filter(lambda x: x.find("_") == -1 and x != "","".join(map(lambda x: ["_", a[x]][map(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], zip(list(a), list(b)))[x]], range(len(a)))).split("_"))
```

Comment: Oops, it appears the question changed while I was writing an answer - the OP does want "abcd" and "bcde" to match, but that wasn't clear when I began.

Answer (score 0):

```
def  IntersectStrings( first,  second):
x = list(first)
#print x
y = list(second)
lst1= []
lst2= []
for i in x:
    if i in y:
        lst1.append(i)
lst2 = sorted(lst1) + []
   # This  above step is an optional if it is required to be sorted      alphabetically use this or else remove it
return ''.join(lst2)

print IntersectStrings('hello','mello' )
```

Comment: The output will be ello as a string