# Intersection with order between two strings

Tags: python, string, intersection

My Question is that if we need to find the intersect between two strings?
How could we do that?

For example `"address"` and `"dress"` should return `"dress"`.
I used a `dict` to implement my function, but I can only sort these characters and not output them with the original order? So how should I modify my code?

```
def IntersectStrings(first,second):
    a={}
    b={}
    for c in first:
        if c in a:
            a[c] = a[c]+1
        else:
            a[c] = 1
    for c in second:
        if c in b:
            b[c] = b[c]+1
        else:
            b[c] = 1
    l = []
    print a,b

    for key in sorted(a):
        if key in b:
            cnt = min(a[key],b[key])
            while(cnt>0):
                l.append(key)
                cnt = cnt-1
    return ''.join(l)

print IntersectStrings('address','dress')
```

Comment: So should `sprinting` and `integer` return `int`?

Comment: this answer seems interesting - difflib module - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7579122/1832058

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of intersecting strings. One way you could create a set of all substrings of each string and then intersect. If you want the biggest intersection just find the max from the resulting set, e.g.:

```
def substrings(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i, len(s)):
            yield s[i:j+1]

def intersect(s1, s2):
    return set(substrings(s1)) & set(substrings(s2))
```

Then you can see the intersections:

```
>>> intersect('address', 'dress')
{'re', 'ss', 'ess', 'es', 'ress', 'dress', 'dres', 'd', 'e', 's', 'res', 'r', 'dre', 'dr'}
>>> max(intersect('address', 'dress'), key=len)
'dress'
>>> max(intersect('sprinting', 'integer'), key=len)
'int'
```